# subtract first and last datetime of an array javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to subtract the first and last element (dates) of an array wich i get from an XML file.

The string has the following format:

```
 27/12/2012 13:09:15
 27/12/2012 13:40:47
 27/12/2012 14:56:43
```

does anyone know how to do the subtract?

best regards

My function is this:

```
 function recorrido() {

 downloadUrl("dates.asp", function(data) {
    var xml = xmlParse(data);
    var markersPath = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");   
    var path = [];


    for (var i = 0; i < markersPath.length; i++) {
    var lat = parseFloat(markersPath[i].getAttribute("lat"));
    var lng = parseFloat(markersPath[i].getAttribute("lng"));
    var timestamp= markersPath[i].getAttribute("timestamp");

    var time = 0;
    time+= Math.abs(timestamp[0]) - Math.abs(timestamp[timestamp.length-1]);

}//finish loop

alert(time);
alert(timestamp[0]);
alert(timestamp[timestamp.length-1]);




}); //end download url
}//end function
```

and the xml whic loads dinamically is this one:

```
<markers>
<marker id="1" lat="37.1914496222793" lng="-3.72511240175617" timestamp="27/12/2012 16:37:03"/>
<marker id="2" lat="37.1914401951048" lng="-3.72517991386109" timestamp="27/12/2012 16:37:05"/>
<marker id="3" lat="37.1914308368611" lng="-3.72523615956726" timestamp="27/12/2012 16:37:07"/>
<marker id="4" lat="37.1914216855078" lng="-3.72525860611944" timestamp="27/12/2012 16:37:09"/>
<marker id="5" lat="37.1913854939084" lng="-3.72528079402709" timestamp="27/12/2012 16:42:38"/>
<marker id="6" lat="37.191367191181" lng="-3.72532568708827" timestamp="27/12/2012 16:42:40"/>
</markers>
```

So what I want to get is the time that the vehicle have been driving.

Comment: Do you already have that as javascript array or you do not know how to make an array from XML and remove first and last items? Also - it would be helpful if you show a code you have for now

Answer (score 2):

Two parts to your question. Array access and date time parsing.

For array access, for an array a, `a[0]` and `a[a.length-1]` are the first and last respectively.

Vanilla Javascript has a `Date.parse` method but that isn't very flexible and didn't work for your particular string format. I would prefer a library like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). Once you do the parsing, you can subtract the dates (presumably time difference in ms?)

Comment: I also recommend Moment.js. It is an excellent library I use all the time :)

Comment: hello, i have updated  my code, but when i put into an alert my elements, there is no any date, just numbers like a 5 for timestamp[0] and another number for the last element of the array.

Comment: Two quick comments. 1. Prefer to use console.log in lieu of alert as that doesn't block JS thread execution. 2. Your debug code is outside the anonymous function where timestamp etc. is defined. Thus, it's outside the scope. If you want to see the real value w/o shadowing, put the debug statement right after the line where you initialized timestamp. Also, w/o parsing the dates, you won't be able to subtract them. Subtracting strings from each other is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the dates into milliseconds, then subtract it to get the difference.

For example:

```
<script>
var date1 = getTimeInMillisecond('27/12/2012 13:09:15');
alert("Date 1: "+date1.getTime());

var date2 = getTimeInMillisecond('27/12/2012 14:56:43');
alert("Date 2: "+date2.getTime());

var diff = date2-date1;
alert(diff/1000 + " seconds");
alert(diff/1000/60 + " minutes");
alert(diff/1000/60/60 + " hours");

function getTimeInMillisecond(timeString) {
    var time1 = '27/12/2012 13:09:15';
    // create date object for time 1
    var dateInfo = timeString.match(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+) (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/);
    return new Date(dateInfo[3],dateInfo[2]-1,dateInfo[1],dateInfo[4],dateInfo[5],dateInfo[6]);
}
</script>
```

Hope that's what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

convert to miliseconds and then calculate the difference:

```
a=['27/12/2012 13:09:15','27/12/2012 13:40:47','27/12/2012 14:56:43'];
alert(arrayDateSpan(a));
function dateToMilisec(str){
    var d=str.match(/([\d]{2})\/([\d]{2})\/([\d]{4}) ([\d]{2}):([\d]{2}):([\d]{2})/i)
    var date=new Date(d[3],d[2],d[1],d[4],d[5],d[6],0);
    return date.getTime();
}
function milisecToDays(unixmilisec){
    var unix=unixmilisec/1000;
    var day=60*60*24;
    var dayrest=unix%day;
    var days=(unix-dayrest)/day;
    var hourrest = dayrest%(60*60);
    var hours= (dayrest-hourrest)/(60*60);
    var minuterest = hourrest%60;
    var minutes=(hourrest-minuterest)/60;
    var seconds=minuterest;
    return days+' Days '+hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;

}
function arrayDateSpan(array){
    diff=dateToMilisec(array[array.length-1])-dateToMilisec(array[0]);
    return milisecToDays(diff);
}
```